# Why is this Boolean false?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, iteration

Why is Python saying that 'e' is not found in strvowel?

I have tried formatting the string as:
'aeiouAEIOU' but that doesn't work either

```
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
strvowel = "'a' 'e' 'i' 'o' 'u' 'A' 'E' 'I' 'O' 'U'"

 if w[0] not in vowel:
        PLw = []
        for element in w:
            v = element.find(strvowel)
        PLw.append(w[v:] + '-' + w[0:v] + 'ay')
        return PLw[0]
if __name__ == '__main__':
#     encrypt(w)
#     decrypt(w)
    print(encrypt('yesterday'))
    print(encrypt('"always!"'))
    print(encrypt('computer'))
```

the print statements should be :

> esterday-yay
>   always!"-"ay
>   omputer-cay

They are currently :

> y-yesterdaay
>   "-"always!ay
>   r-computeay

When the word (w) is input, it should find the first occurence of a vowel:
ex. 'yesterday' would be 'e'
BUT it's calling false for each character (even vowels)

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know what `w` is.

Comment: w is any word. It is explained if you look below the code block

Comment: `'y'.find(strvowel)` = `-1`, which you then pass to index `w`.  `w[-1:]` = `y`.  `find` returns the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. **Return -1 if sub is not found**.

Comment: it is supposed to iterate through each letter in w till a vowel is found (in this instance 'e'), but each iteration yields -1 indicating that no vowel is present. I'm just wondering how I could debug so that the vowels are caught

Comment: It works like `'find'.find('i')` returns `1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that variable `w` is the word `yesterday` per your example, a good way to search for it would be to define a function and return the first occurance.

```py
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
w = "yesterday"
def find_first_vowel(string):
    for char in string:
        if char in vowel:
            return char

print(find_first_vowel(w))
```

Answer (score 1):

When `w` is a word like “yesterday”, `element` is a character like “y”. When you say

```
v = element.find(strvowel)
```

you’re asking for the location of “'a' 'e' 'i' 'o' 'u' 'A' 'E' 'I' 'O' 'U'” in “y” (it can never be there).

My best guess is that you want `v` to be the index of the first vowel. You’ve already created one correct way to check whether a character is a vowel:

```
if w[0] not in vowel:
```

so remove `strvowel` and reuse that:

```
v = -1  # TODO: think about what happens when there are no vowels

for i, letter in enumerate(w):
    if letter in vowel:
        v = i
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

so you just want to find the first vowel?
that's what regular expressions are for.

```py
#python standard regular expression library
>>>import re

#prepare your vowels. this means "any of those letters"
>>> vowels = re.compile("[aeiouyAEIOUY]")

#find the match. returns a Match Object. often used as a `if vowels.match(string)` too
>>> vowels.match("yesterday")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='y'>
>>> match = vowels.match("yesterday")
#  look as the object for fun
>>> match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='y'>

#find the result
>>> match[0]
'y'
# or this way
>>> match.group()
'y'
```

So to append "-ay" to the first vowel found, you just need to do

```
def append_yay(string):
    match = vowels.match(str)
    if match:
        return match.group() + "ay"


append_yay("yesterday")
```

and you get your `-yay`.